# How can I test relative friction at home?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag, home-experiment

My 7 year old is anxious to test whether or not banana peels are slippery. He has been waiting for 2 years for the science fair to come back. We have the idea to test different types of banana peels (fresh, day old, squished, green, frozen etc) but we are unsure how to authentically see which ones are more slippery. Is there a way to test for friction (or lack there of) in our kitchen?

Comment: Welcome to physics SE! Note that your question "Is there a way to test for friction (or lack there of) in our kitchen?" is fairly open-ended, and has the potential to gain answers that are all technically "correct". We prefer more specific questions that have the potential for a single correct answer, and we prefer they focus on the relevant physics concepts. It might help to edit your question to focus specifically on what you do not fully understand about friction that is preventing you from formalizing the experiment you would like to perform.

Comment: Bananas are difficult. Maybe start with materials available in more geometric shapes first. Or apply "banana grease" to the same block of material and compare against other lubricants.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest think I can think of is a block or plank and an adjustable ramp.

You could set the ramp at different angles (or just set the end of the ramp at different heights), put your material on the ramp, then place the block on top of the tested material.

For elementary school, you don't need the trig and calculations of the coefficient of friction.  Instead you can just compare at what height different products cause the "standard block" to slide.  Slippery substance, block slides at a lower height/angle.

I'm thinking of something like a smallish rectangle of plywood with something heavy on top.  But just about anything that is able to be repeatably used and can sit on top of the tested product should be good.

Comment: Banana peels tend to leave behind residue. I wonder if that would have an effect on repeated experiments?

Comment: Could be.  Good to either clean it up for repeatability or to discuss it in the report.

Comment: Replace a fresh layer of newspaper under the banana peel at each experiment. Tape it to the plank on the border, on the high-side

Comment: Wonderful theory but an issue with actual experimentation is going to be adjusting height without ramp motion triggering the slide early. Provide a way to rest the ramp at different angles/heights and release block when things are still. It's a static vs sliding friction thing. Will also make collecting data easier. Use blocks to hold up the ramp. After test block slides put them aside and put the test block on top of them. That will record how far it got. Repeat and when you're done you have a winners podium.

Answer (score 4):

This is only a supplementary answer to BowlOfRed's good one.

Maybe it is not yet suitable for a 7 year old, but a special point could be made by showing if certain states of banana peel (let's call them 'fermented'...) probably do not experience simple Coulomb friction ($F_F=\mu F_N$) but actually fluid friction/viscosity ($F_F=\gamma v$), which would explain why they are so slippery. As fluid friction is velocity dependent, it shows no stiction (fluid friction is also what makes ice slippery under pressure, e.g. with skates!).

One could try to show that a banana peel in that state allows objects to slide even with the smallest drag forces (or at the smallest angles of the inclined plane, see BowlOfReds answer). Maybe this also depends on the weight of the objects, because the starch/water mixture in the banana pulp probably liquefies under pressure (similar to what ice does). So, maybe, lighter objects still stick at rather large angles, but heavier objects slide at almost any angle.